# Owl Slider 2, need to animate elements before goes next slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm using [Owl Carousel 2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

Visit this link and see how I want to be the animation for those elements:

[Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/Tnly4d0l0SE) - Below this video below in the description section you will find the ***CODEPEN*** of this demo work.

Note: So basically what I want is that I need to finish the animation of elements before goes to the next slide. You can see the details on the Youtube Link that I shared.

Comment: Can you please provide some actual code and a snippet that showcases what you currently have implemented. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have my code on the Youtube Video Description. As you can see that I mentioned it.